# Como buscar um elemento no XML usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

Quero fazer uma procura por determinado elemento (no caso nome) em um documento `XML`, usando apenas um `input` do tipo texto.

## Código do que já consegui

```js
TagXML = function() {

  dados = "<doc>"
  dados = dados + "<clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<nome>Maria Adriana</nome>"
  dados = dados + "<telefone>(11) 5555-1234</telefone>"
  dados = dados + "<idade>2</idade>"
  dados = dados + "</clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<nome>Giovana Pereira</nome>"
  dados = dados + "<telefone>(11) 5555-6789</telefone>"
  dados = dados + "<idade>25</idade>"
  dados = dados + "</clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<nome>Ricardo Ramos</nome>"
  dados = dados + "<telefone>(11) 5555-6090</telefone>"
  dados = dados + "<idade>26</idade>"
  dados = dados + "</clientes>"
  dados = dados + "</doc>"

  // Executa uma consulta XML e armazena em busca
  var busca = document.getElementById('campo').value;

  if (window.DOMParser) { // Demais Navegadores
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(dados, "text/xml")
  } else { // Internet Explorer
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(dados);
  }

  // Armazena na var registro o conteudo de uma tag "doc"
  registro = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("doc")[0];

  // Guarda na var nome o conteudo de uma tag "nome"
  nome = registro.getElementsByTagName("nome");

  // Laço dentro da tag "nome" para cada tag "nome" que encontrar
  for (var i in nome) {
    // Verificando se houve alguma busca com sucesso
    if (nome[i].firstChild.textContent == busca) {
      // Exibindo os resultados encontrados
      alert('existe sim');
      break;
    } else {
      alert('não existe');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="campo" />
<input type="button" value="Procurar" onclick="TagXML();" />

<pre>Ex.: Maria Adriana, Giovana Pereira ou Ricardo Ramos</pre>
```

---

A ideia é emitir um `alert()` indicando se o resultado existe ou não.

Para isso preciso ler o `XML` e fazer a seleção de acordo com o índice `[i]` percorrendo cada elemento da tag "nome".

## O que esta acontecendo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problema - Os três nomes existem dentro do `XML`, mas ele só confirma o primeiro, e anula o restante.

O laço que deveria retornar o número da posição do índice de cada "nome", somente retorna o primeiro índice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu problema esta no `break`.... mude para `continue` e seja feliz

Código explicado (com exemplo) do funcionamento de `break` e `continue` em `javascript` [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/oapg5axm/2/)

```js
TagXML = function() {

  dados = "<doc>"
  dados = dados + "<clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<nome>Maria Adriana</nome>"
  dados = dados + "<telefone>(11) 5555-1234</telefone>"
  dados = dados + "<idade>2</idade>"
  dados = dados + "</clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<nome>Giovana Pereira</nome>"
  dados = dados + "<telefone>(11) 5555-6789</telefone>"
  dados = dados + "<idade>25</idade>"
  dados = dados + "</clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<nome>Ricardo Ramos</nome>"
  dados = dados + "<telefone>(11) 5555-6090</telefone>"
  dados = dados + "<idade>26</idade>"
  dados = dados + "</clientes>"
  dados = dados + "</doc>"

  // Executa uma consulta XML e armazena em busca
  var busca = document.getElementById('campo').value;

  if (window.DOMParser) { // Demais Navegadores
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(dados, "text/xml")
  } else { // Internet Explorer
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(dados);
  }

  // Armazena na var registro o conteudo de uma tag "doc"
  registro = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("doc")[0];

  // Guarda na var nome o conteudo de uma tag "nome"
  nome = registro.getElementsByTagName("nome");

  // Laço dentro da tag "nome" para cada tag "nome" que encontrar
  for (i = 0; i < nome.length; i++) {
    // Verificando se houve alguma busca com sucesso
    if (nome[i].firstChild.textContent == busca) {
      // Exibindo os resultados encontrados
      alert('existe sim');
      break;
    } else {
      alert('nao existe na posicao' + i);
      continue;
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="campo" />
<input type="button" value="Procurar" onclick="TagXML();" />

<pre>Ex.: Maria Adriana, Giovana Pereira ou Ricardo Ramos</pre>
```

---

**[obs] eu faria diferente:**

```js
TagXML = function() {

  dados = "<doc>"
  dados = dados + "<clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<nome>Maria Adriana</nome>"
  dados = dados + "<telefone>(11) 5555-1234</telefone>"
  dados = dados + "<idade>2</idade>"
  dados = dados + "</clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<nome>Giovana Pereira</nome>"
  dados = dados + "<telefone>(11) 5555-6789</telefone>"
  dados = dados + "<idade>25</idade>"
  dados = dados + "</clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<clientes>"
  dados = dados + "<nome>Ricardo Ramos</nome>"
  dados = dados + "<telefone>(11) 5555-6090</telefone>"
  dados = dados + "<idade>26</idade>"
  dados = dados + "</clientes>"
  dados = dados + "</doc>"

  // Executa uma consulta XML e armazena em busca
  var busca = document.getElementById('campo').value;

  if (window.DOMParser) { // Demais Navegadores
    parser = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(dados, "text/xml")
  } else { // Internet Explorer
    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(dados);
  }

  // Armazena na var registro o conteudo de uma tag "doc"
  registro = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("doc")[0];

  // Guarda na var nome o conteudo de uma tag "nome"
  nome = registro.getElementsByTagName("nome");

  // Laço dentro da tag "nome" para cada tag "nome" que encontrar
  for (i = 0; i < nome.length; i++) {
    // Verificando se houve alguma busca com sucesso
    if (nome[i].firstChild.textContent == busca) {
      // Exibindo os resultados encontrados
      var existe = 1;
      var linha = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if(existe){ alert("existe sim!! na linha: "+ linha) }else{ alert("nao existe") }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="campo" />
<input type="button" value="Procurar" onclick="TagXML();" />

<pre>Ex.: Maria Adriana, Giovana Pereira ou Ricardo Ramos</pre>
```

Comment: O `continue` é opcional até. Mas é isso aí :) Diego: aproveita e declara esse monte de variável sem `var` que você tem aí, porque isso tudo está vazando pro escopo global e pode te causar problemas.

Comment: Uma outra dica, o Snippets aqui da rede tem uma ótima ferramenta de identação(quase todo bom editor profissional[e a maioria dos free inclusive] tem), seus códigos geralmente são muito mal identados, isso prejudica na hora de alguém tentar achar uma solução.... inclusive você mesmo pode acabar se confundindo