# Como realizar uma buscar interna pelo id?

Tags: javascript

Como posso fazer para saber se um determinado elemento existe, via campo `input`?

**Exemplo**

```html
<html>

<body>

<input type="text" id="txt"><input type="button" value="mais" onclick="busca()">

<pre>Ex.: vaca, boi, porco ou galinha</pre>


<div id='vaca'></div>

<div id='boi'></div>

<div id='porco'></div>

<div id='galinha'></div>

</body>

<script>
    function busca() {

        var str = document.getElementById('txt').value;

        var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

            var el = o bj[i].id

            if (document.getElementById(el) != "undefined") {

                alert('existe sim');
                break;

            } else {

                alert('não existe');
                break;

            }

        }

    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Não sei porque, mas essa pergunta me parece bem similar com essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180595/como-buscar-um-elemento-no-xml-usando-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function busca() {

  var str = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var existe = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].id == str) {
      existe = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (existe) {
    alert('existe sim');
  } else {
    alert('não existe');
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt"><input type="button" value="mais" onclick="busca()">

<div id='vaca'></div>

<div id='boi'></div>

<div id='porco'></div>

<div id='galinha'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Da forma que está fazendo não tem necessidade de percorrer todos os elementos, teria se estivesse procurando um elemento pelo atributo `class` (que pode se repetir). Um `id` é único por página, logo, se [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) retornar algo é porque o elemento existe:

```js
function busca() {
  var str = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  
  if(document.getElementById(str))
    console.log(str + ' existe.');
  else
    console.log(str + ' ñ existe');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt"><input type="button" value="mais" onclick="busca()">

<pre>Ex.: vaca, boi, porco ou galinha</pre>

<div id='vaca'></div>
<div id='boi'></div>
<div id='porco'></div>
<div id='galinha'></div>
```